# Convert request.getParameterMap() to bean with list of objects

Tags: java, javabeans

I want to convert form data directly into a bean. Originally I used spring for that, but in my current project we are not allowed to use spring anymore so I tried to do something similiar with the help of Apache BeanUtils. My bean looks like this:

```
public class MyBean {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
    private List<FooBar> fooBars;
}
public class FooBar {
    private int id;
}
```

After submitting the form the request.getParameterMap() method gives me the following map:

```
"foo" : "Some text",
"bar" : "Other text",
"foobars[0].id" : "1",
"foobars[1].id" : "2",
"foobars[2].id" : "3"
```

The code I use for the conversion looks like this:

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean();
BeanUtils.populate(bean, request.getParameterMap());
```

With the spring data binder it was no problem to convert those values into the bean, but the dot notation somehow does not work with BeanUtils. Does anyone know how the input must look like so that BeanUtils can transform `foobars` to a list of objects? Or maybe you know another library which is capable of that?

Answer (score 0):

`BeanUtils.populate` does not seem to support nested properties:

> This method uses Java reflection APIs to identify corresponding
>   "property setter" method names, and deals with setter arguments of
>   type **String, boolean, int, long, float, and double. In addition, array
>   setters for these types (or the corresponding primitive types) can
>   also be identified**.

I found this other method, [`BeanUtils.copyProperties`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-), and here it is specified that

> If the origin "bean" is actually a Map, it is assumed to contain
>   String-valued **simple** property names as the keys.

So I guess you have no way to do that with `BeanUtils`. But I may have a solution, using `PropertyUtils`. This class has a lot of static methods, among them there are:

- [`setProperty`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#setProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)
- [`setNestedProperty`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#setNestedProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

I have not tried it, but this is a possible approach:

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : request.getParameterMap())
{
    try {
        PropertyUtils.setProperty(bean, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException exc) {
        PropertyUtils.setNestedProperty(bean, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

I would not know whether the conversion from `String` to `Integer` is automatic. Let me know.